# how do you group select_tag and text_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a form where a user can select an existing category, or define their own.

My form looks something like this...

```
<%= f.select :category, category_options, prompt: "Select">
<%= f.text_field :category %>
```

However, this UI is confusing. The user can select something in the select box, and type in a custom category. In this case, the final result is not obvious.

Do you guys have any recommendations on how to handle this situation?

Comment: you can have a combo box. This question is already there on Stack overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122105/combo-box-in-rails-3).. there are a couple of links like [this](http://chakrabarty.com/pp_editable_dropdown.html) or [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/VjL4rw5ul1M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, text field will be hidden and disabled
Dropdown should have "OTHER" option
when user selects "OTHER" option,
text field will be enabled and displayed,then user should be able to enter value there.

Comment: That's a good idea. How do you distinguish between the two inputs in the ActiveRecord? Both inputs are named :category, one contains "Other", the second contains something else. Depending on the order the accessors gets called, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot that when you disable a text field, it does not get submitted.